# Why i cant set a cookie on php?

Tags: php, cookies, setcookie

i got an issue with cookies and i can solve it...

I've read some tutorials, but i still cant create a cookie...

Well... I am trying to create a referrer system, it will provide a link to my users with a &id=number at the end. (this number will be related to their account, so i can identify and give them a reward later).

I've tried many ways, like:

```
 setcookie('ref', $c_value, time()+86400, '.mydomain.com', '/');
 setcookie('ref', $c_value, time()+86400, '/', '.mydomain.com');
 setcookie('ref', 'test', time()+86400, '/', '.mydomain.com');
 setcookie('ref', 'test', time()+86400, '/', '.mydomain.com');
 setcookie('ref', 'test', time()+86400, '/', 'www.mydomain.com');

 $time = time()+86400; setcookie('ref', 'test', '$time', '/', 'www.mydomain.com/');
```

PS: I've tryied all separately.

But none of them seems to work, do i have to turn on some feature on php.ini?

Im trying to implement this code to:

```
 if(!empty($_GET['id'])){
    $c_value = $_GET['id'];     
    setcookie('ref', $c_value, time()+86400, '/', '.mydomain.com');
 }
```

I have also tried without the $_GET function, but no matter what i do, it doesnt work...

PS2: I am using google analytics and facebook plugins that also create cookies, do they interfer in something? And i am also using SESSIONID.

Comment: Please use the code markup tool `{ }` to put literal code in your question. Then it won't be reformatted.

Comment: What makes you think the cookie isn't being set?

Comment: I have no idea, i've searched the code around the internet and seems to be ok... I've also tried to copy and paste some codes, but it also didnt work...

Edit: Sorry, i havent read your answer well... I am checking trought the "F12", developers function from google chrome... I've also tried to check trought a code on php, like:

if(exists($_COOKIE['ref'])){
echo $_COOKIE['ref'];
}

Comment: Make sure you haven't produced any output before you call `setcookie()`.

Comment: Yes. I can see cookies from facebook and google analytics, but i cant see mine...

Comment: Turn on `error_reporting(E_ALL)`, see if there are any warnings coming when you try to set the cookie.

Comment: Ohhhhh, thats it!

I was placing the code at the end of <head> section...
Now i have placed it at the first command of the entire page...
Thank you! It worked now :)

Comment: How can i give you that positive answer? :)
I am new here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setcookie` works by sending an HTTP header before the response body. All functions that send headers (e.g. `setcookie`, `session_start`, and `header`) have to be called before you output anything in the body.

So either move the `setcookie()` function earlier in your script, or use the output buffering functions to buffer the output until after you call it.

Comment: That's it!

Thank you, i have placed it at the first command of the entire page and now its working :)